# Webscraping using R - the full website data is not loading

Tags: r, web-scraping

I am trying to webscrape the following website using R:
https://www.ebi.ac.uk/gxa/genes/ensg00000177455?bs=%7B%22homo%20sapiens%22%3A%5B%22ORGANISM_PART%22%5D%7D&ds=%7B%22kingdom%22%3A%5B%22animals%22%5D%7D#differential

I would like the information within the table.  It doesn't have to be in any particular format - I just need table information.

However, when I use:

```
library(RCurl)
website = getURL("https://www.ebi.ac.uk/gxa/genes/ensg00000177455?bs=%7B%22homo%20sapiens%22%3A%5B%22ORGANISM_PART%22%5D%7D&ds=%7B%22kingdom%22%3A%5B%22animals%22%5D%7D#differential")
```

The table information is not present in the `website` object.

I thought it might be because the website is in javascript, but when I tried scraping using [PhantomJS](https://phantomjs.org/), I didn't get the table information either.

For note, my .js script I used was:

```
#!/usr/bin/env phantomjs

"use strict";

var system = require('system');
var fs = require('fs');

var page = new WebPage()

page.open(url, function (status) {
  just_wait();
});

function just_wait() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    fs.write('temp.html', page.content, 'w');
    phantom.exit();
  }, 2500);
}
```

Can anyone suggest how to get this data in R?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you right-click on the page, select 'Inspect Element' and go to the 'Network tab', you can see the requests being made by the page. If you refresh the page, you see one large XHR (data) request being made, to https://www.ebi.ac.uk/gxa/json/search/differential_results?geneQuery=%255B%257B%2522value%2522%253A%2522ensg00000177455%2522%257D%255D&conditionQuery=&species=homo+sapiens,
which contains the table you want.

This can be easily read in R using for example `jsonlite`:

```
url <- "https://www.ebi.ac.uk/gxa/json/search/differential_results?geneQuery=%255B%257B%2522value%2522%253A%2522ensg00000177455%2522%257D%255D&conditionQuery=&species=homo+sapiens"

res <- jsonlite::read_json(url)

# the first row
res[["results"]][[1]]
```

For turning this nested list structure into a data.frame, I recommend looking at https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/hoist.html.